# Hold a div panel when the mouse is over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a div that shows on mousemove and hides after a certain delay. I have achieved the aforementioned thing.

I have attached the code below-

```js
var nav = $('.nav');
var movementTimer = null;

var $doc = $(document);


$doc.on('mousemove', function(e) {
  nav.addClass('show');
});

$doc.on('mousemove', function(e) {
  clearTimeout(movementTimer);
  movementTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    nav.removeClass("show");
  }, 500);
})
```

```css
.nav {
  background: #111;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -100px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
.nav.show {
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">This is a funny nav</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.unevent.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/129/

According to this code, the div goes away after certain time.
Now the question that I have is how to hold the div when I hover or mouse over it. 
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `.nav.show, .nav:hover` should do the trick, making the rule applicable in both situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if target element (under e.target) has class **nav**

Check out this fiddle:

```js
var nav = $('.nav');
var movementTimer = null;

var $doc = $(document);


$doc.on('mousemove', function(e) {
nav.addClass('show');    
});

$doc.on('mousemove', function(e)
    {
        clearTimeout(movementTimer);
        if(!$(e.target).hasClass("nav")) {
            movementTimer = setTimeout(function()
            {
                nav.removeClass("show");
            }, 500);
        }
    })
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  height: 8000px;
}


.nav {
  background: #111;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -100px;
  left: 0px; 
  transition:.4s ease-in-out;
}

.nav.show{
  bottom:0px;
  transition:.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">This is a funny nav</div>     
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.unevent.js"></script>
```

There is a function .hasClass(class) that returns **true** if element has provided class. So simply insert an if statement that check is element has **not** class *nav* and execute timer.

Comment: This is *probably* computationally more expensive than the answer by me or @sudharsan-s, does anyone know for sure?

Comment: @SworrubWehttam I think this should be less expensive, but wrapping it in jQuery does increase the cost (otherwise you could easily just match `e.target.className.indexOf('nav')`, which isn't very expensive to do at all). At that point though, I don't see why 'computationally expensive' is even argument if you opt for jQuery in the first place...

Comment: @somethinghere Yeah I was under the impression `mouseover` and `mouseout` would do less checking than `mousemove` until @sudharsan-s pointed out the difference to me, but surely his answer would be less expensive seeing as it's not doing the `e.target` check on every small movement? But you're right, at the end of the day it will be a very small difference.

Comment: @SworrubWehttam The `e.target` 'check' is done regardless (the browser includes it inside the `event` that gets passed), so that is there anyhow. But yes, executing the code _once_ is probably going to save you some cycles - which is what `mouseleave` and the sort allow you to do.

Comment: @somethinghere _"The `e.target` 'check' is done regardless"_ <- That's very useful knowledge, I always used to shy away from overusing it for some reason. That will make my life marginally easier.

Comment: @SworrubWehttam `e.target` is just a value, a reference to an element that triggered the event. The system is processing these all the time as it needs to keep an eye out for events to send, so yeah, everything inside passed objects is mostly already processed and computationally inexpensive to use. Make use of them!

Answer (score 2):

You just use `.mouseenter` event for hold the div and `.mouseleave` event for release the div. For your context the code should be like this.

```
var nav = $('.nav');
var movementTimer = null;

var $doc = $(document);


$doc.on('mouseenter', function(e) {
nav.addClass('show');    
});

$doc.on('mouseleave', function(e)
    {
        clearTimeout(movementTimer);
        movementTimer = setTimeout(function()
        {
            nav.removeClass("show");
        }, 500);
    })
```

[**Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/132/)

Comment: Wasn't even aware of these 2 as opposed to my answer, do you know if there is any difference between `mouseenter` and `mouseover`, `mouseleave` and `mouseout`?

Comment: MouseOver():

Will fire upon entering an element and whenever any mouse movements occur within the element.
MouseEnter():

Will fire upon entering an element.

Comment: The mouseout event triggers when the mouse pointer leaves any child elements as well the selected element.

The mouseleave event is only triggered when the mouse pointer leaves the selected element.

Comment: What I wanted was for the div to stay only when I mouse over it or hover over it. In your solution, the div is staying even when mouse movement stops.So if you can improve the solution somehow - @Sudharsan

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? I've just replaced the methods with `mouseover` and `mouseout` respectively, instead of `mousemove`.
Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/130/

Answer (score 0):

You can update your JS code from

```
$doc.on('mousemove', function(e) {
 nav.addClass('show');    
 });

$doc.on('mousemove', function(e)
 {
    clearTimeout(movementTimer);
    movementTimer = setTimeout(function()
    {
        nav.removeClass("show");
    }, 500);
})
```

to

```
var nav = $('.nav'),
    movementTimer = null,
    $doc = $(document);

$doc.hover(function(){
   nav.addClass('show');

}, function(){
   nav.removeClass("show");
})
```

Also don't use var again and again for best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to mouseover and mouseout event of nav bar. Checkout the working code

```js
var nav = $('.nav');
var movementTimer = null;

var $doc = $(document);

function showNav(){
 $doc.off('mousemove', showNav);
 nav.addClass("show");
  movementTimer = setTimeout(autoHide, 500);
}

function autoHide(){
 nav.removeClass("show");
  $doc.on('mousemove', showNav);
}

$doc.on('mousemove', showNav);

$('.nav').on('mouseover', function(e){
 clearTimeout(movementTimer);
  e.stopPropagation();
})
$('.nav').on('mouseout', function(e)
{
 $doc.on('mousemove', showNav);
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  height: 8000px;
}


.nav {
  background: #111;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -100px;
  left: 0px; 
  transition:.4s ease-in-out;
}

.nav.show{
  bottom:0px;
  transition:.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">This is a funny nav</div>     
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.unevent.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have simply added `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` inside the `mousemove` function. 
And removed the class `.show` if the `.nav` has the class show.

```js
var nav = $('.nav');
var movementTimer = null;
var $doc = $(document);
$doc.on('mousemove', function(e) {
nav.addClass('show');   
  $(".nav").on({
      mouseenter: function () {
          nav.addClass('show');
      },
      mouseleave: function () {
          clearTimeout(movementTimer);
          movementTimer = setTimeout(function()
          {
              nav.removeClass("show");
          }, 500);
          nav.removeClass("show");
      }
  });
});
$doc.on('mousemove', function(e)
    {
        clearTimeout(movementTimer);
        if(!$(e.target).hasClass("nav")) {
            movementTimer = setTimeout(function()
            {
                nav.removeClass("show");
            }, 500);
        }
    })
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  height: 8000px;
}


.nav {
  background: #111;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -100px;
  left: 0px; 
  transition:.4s ease-in-out;
}
.nav.show{
  bottom:0px;
  transition:.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">This is a funny nav</div>     
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.unevent.js"></script>
```